# Issue creating admin user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm having issues creating an admin user using in my controller. What is the problem here?

Here is my code:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private SwagExchangeDb db = new SwagExchangeDb();

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var ac  = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ac));
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ac));
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "hello@gmail.com", Email = "hello@gmail.com"};
        userManager.Create(user, "Hello1234!");
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");

    }
```

Getting error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'UserId not found.'

Comment: Which one of code gives you the error?

Comment: It's breaking on userManager.AddToRole(user.Id,"admin")

Comment: Your update is a completely new question. I would suggest you to rollback the edit and ask a new question, since changing the question after it was answered is not considered a good behavior here

Comment: I will go ahead and do. My bad, I'm new here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, we were all new here at some point. Glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the user by the Id which you don't have. You need to query for the user after creating it. Also, you should be disposing the context after finish using it:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    using (var ac  = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ac));
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(ac));
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "hello@gmail.com", Email = "hello@gmail.com"};
        userManager.Create(user, "Hello1234!");
        roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("admin"));

        user = userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName).Result;

        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "admin");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't he just put, `userManager.AddToRole(user.UserName, "admin");` without `.FindByUserName`?

Comment: @Jimenemex No, there's no overload that accepts the name of the user, only the Id

Comment: 'ApplicationUserManger' does not contain a definition for 'FindByUserName' and no extension method 'FindByUserName' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationUserManger' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: @PJ.SQL Oops, my bad, fixed!

Comment: Updated my original post to include new error I'm getting when I navigate to the products controller in the browser. However, user is now being added which is great!

Comment: Is there an issue with my connection string?